# JSON_EXTRACT does not exist in mysql with mysql 5.7.22

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb, innodb, rds

My query is

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT('{"test_Id":"661_0t7sb-52","user_id":"661"}','user_id');
```

and I'm getting error

> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> 1305 - FUNCTION test.JSON_EXTRACT does not exist

how to solve this?

Comment: I have a feeling this is a 'usage' not 'missing function' issue. 1.Where is the FROM for the table where your json is stored? 2.Have you got your parameters back to front? 3.Also, as I understand it, the 'column name' parameter should not be in quotes. Apologies if I have missed something.

Comment: Make sure you are actually using mysql 5.7.22 (e.g. with `select @@version`), you might be connected to a different server than you think. Also make sure that this is actually the query you are running (and is not reinterpreted by some framework or something). A side note (although it would not account for that error message), you need to use `$.user_id` as the path.

Comment: @Solarflare is correct. You might be using the MySQL *client* 5.7, but you must make sure that the MySQL *server* you connect to is 5.7.8 or later.

Comment: thank you very much all , i've updated mysql and resolved the problem